# Does my "Play Solo" personal record get updated when I beat my time in "Hot-Seat"?

Tags: trackmania-forever

When I am using the same account that I use for "Play Solo" while I am playing hot-seat with friends, would my personal record that I see in "Play Solo" be updated? Would I be able to gain medals for levels that way? What about levels where I don't have the prerequisites for playing them yet, e.g. no bronze medal in the previous levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you play *hot-seat* your personal records will be updated and you are able to gain medals. You can play, set records, and gain medals for maps which are not yet available to you in *Play Solo*.

Source: I played the Black Coast track (CoastE1) in *hot-seat* and beat the gold medal time. When I unlocked CoastE1 by having gold medals in all other Coast tracks, the personal record and the gold medal were already showing for it.